# Passing lambda expression as function parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

Function like `bool decide(bool x)` can be passed in method as parameter as functor as:

```
foo(Func<bool,bool> lambda)
```

We can have lambda expression like `()=>{int x=8; x=x+2;}` that does not take anything and return anything. Lets say I want to pass such function as parameter to another method `bar` then how can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `Func`. If you don't want to return value, then you must use `Action`.

For example:

```
Action<int> example1 = (int x) => Console.WriteLine("Write {0}", x);
example1.Invoke(1); // or example1(1);

Action example3 = () => Console.WriteLine("Done");
example3.Invoke(); // or example3();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want an [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Presumably it'll do more work than set and manipulate a local variable, though?